# import problem for discord and telegram bot python

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio, telegram-bot, python-multithreading

I have a telegram bot like this:

```
from create_tg import tg_bot
import sellbot

@tg_bot.message_handler(commands=['addqueue'])
def checker(message:Message):
    sellbot.addqueue(message.from_user.id)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

sellbot looks like this:

```
def send_chart(platform, channel_id, msg):
    if platform == 'tg':
        if msg == 'invalid':
            tg_bot.send_message(channel_id, 'invalid')
        else:
            tg_bot.send_photo(channel_id, msg)


def queue_handler():
    while True:
        id, platform = queue[0]
        send_chart(platform, id)
        queue.pop(0)


from create_tg import tg_bot
def add_queue(channel_id):
    queue.append([channel_id])
    if not any(t.name == 'handler' and t.is_alive() for t in threading.enumerate()):
        threading.Thread(name='handler', target=queue_handler).start()
```

but now I also need to add a telegram bot that does the same thing so that they work in parallel with the telegram. But as I understand it, you can’t create a bot discord with a token at the beginning to make a similar file like create_tg, and if you make a discord in one file and then import the bot into sellbot, this will cause a recursive import error (since sellbot imports ds_bot, and it imports sellbot) and the bot will start because of bot.run(). Please let me know if you have a solution to this problem or if you have encountered a similar one.

Comment: You will need to use Treads